# Pré selecionar primeiro elemento do array

Tags: angularjs, angular, ionic, typescript, ionic3

**Meu select**

```
 <ion-item>
   <ion-label floating color="primary" interface="popover">Opções de Parcelamento</ion-label>
   <ion-icon name="pricetags"></ion-icon>
   <ion-select class="myCustomSelect" [(ngModel)]="formaVezes" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone:true}">
     <ion-option *ngFor="let p of parcelamentosArray" [value]="p.type" [selected]="p.type[0]" > {{ p.value}}  </ion-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

**Meu array**

**console.log(this.parcelamentosArray);**

```
(8) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {type: "1"value: "1x de R$ 38,50 (sem juros)"}
1: {type: "2"value: "2x de R$ 20,12 - Total: R$ 40,24 (2.99% a.m)"}
2: {type: "3", value: "3x de R$ 13,61 - Total: R$ 40,82 (2.99% a.m)"}
3: {type: "4", value: "4x de R$ 10,36 - Total: R$ 41,42 (2.99% a.m)"}
4: {type: "5", value: "5x de R$ 8,40 - Total: R$ 42,02 (2.99% a.m)"}
5: {type: "6", value: "6x de R$ 7,11 - Total: R$ 42,63 (2.99% a.m)"}
6: {type: "7", value: "7x de R$ 6,18 - Total: R$ 43,24 (2.99% a.m)"}
7: {type: "8", value: "8x de R$ 5,48 - Total: R$ 43,86 (2.99% a.m)"}
```

Como posso pré Selecionar o primeiro elemento do array? De maneira que a primeira opção venha sempre selecionada.

```
0: {type: "1"value: "1x de R$ 38,50 (sem juros)"}
```

Comment: tente assim `<ion-select class="myCustomSelect" [(ngModel)]="formaVezes" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone:true}">
     <ion-option *ngFor="let p of parcelamentosArray" [value]="p.type" [selected]="p[0]" > {{ p.value}}  </ion-option>
  </ion-select>`

Comment: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined

Comment: Use a diretiva `ngModelChange` para detectar alterações em seu select. Veja essa reposta: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41160860/2570426

Comment: Ainda sem solução!

Comment: tente isso  p?.type assim

Comment: Quando vc carrega/monta o Array "parcelamentosArray" no TypeScript, ou inicia a view, faça com que o "formaVezes" receba "parcelamentosArray[0]" (formaVezes = parcelamentosArray[0]). Não precisa fazer isso na tela, faça no controller.

Comment: Eu já não tenho mais acesso a esse projeto, mas parando para refletir desde jeito daria certo... Obrigado pela resposta!